# Render video from js into html

Tags: javascript, html, django, qr-code, scanning

I'm new here and have a question. How can I render the webcam video from JavaScript into HTML? I want to scan QR-Codes in my browser and while scanning there should be the video from the camera for better user experience (easier to find the qr-code). For scanning the QR-Codes, I use Instascan. My code looks something like this:

**HTML:**

```html
<div class="video-container">
   <div class="overlay-box">
      <video id="preview"></video>
   </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```js
let scanner = new Instascan.Scanner({ video: document.getElementById('preview') });

// When starting scanning, activate via css
document.getElementById("preview").style.display = "block";

// When stopping scanning, deactivate via css
document.getElementById("preview").style.display = "none";
```

I tried without the css stuff, but that was not a problem. It should be a problem with the scanner ig...

Expecting: that it render it into the html file that I can see the camera output while scanning

Thanks for every help!
PS: If it's an important information (idk); its inside a Django project

Comment: Perhaps you run `Instascan.Scanner` before the element exists in the DOM, i.e. your JS may be loaded above the element - of course, then you'd see an error in the browser *developer* tools console, so, surely you'd report that in your question

Comment: Yes the problem was the import of the script in the top. Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understood right, you are trying to use the user's webcam to read the QR code, is that right?
If so, you can try to use the `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()` to handle it.
you can have more information about this method here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia

Comment: Yes that's right! Thanks for help, I was able to fix it, I added the script in the top of the html file lol. Thanks @Jaromanda X